# Flutter How to get uber or ola like car icon moving on google maps

Tags: android, flutter, dart, maps, flutter-animation

I am working on a bus tracking app in flutter but struck at making an moving bus icon animation with google_maps_flutter i tried using markers but it doesn't have any animation on marker i dont how to tackle this situation is there anything to make moving anmation with markers in maps

Comment: Hi. Have you found a solution?

Comment: not yet I am using platform native view right now.

Comment: @Saikumarreddyatluri do you find any solution? How do you create native for this feature on Flutter?

Comment: I have written the code on native side and using platformview widget in flutter embedded the native view in flutter

Answer (score 6):

For this kind of apps you need a source to receive location from in real-time [ you can use node.js and socket.io for backend ], like driver app [in driver app listen for location changes], You don't need animation for markers while receiving live location from the driver app call the method that adds marker on the map use driver's unique id as marker id every time you call updateDriverMarkersWithCircle() method, here is the method that I used for this purpose, it gets called every time the drivers' location is received, this method will update the marker if the received data has same id(which will look like moving cars) else it will add a new marker on the map using driver's id: 
 [here is the output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NR501.jpg)

```
void updateDriverMarkersWithCircle( Map newLocalData ) async{
    final Uint8List markerIcon = await getBytesFromAsset('assets/images/yellow_car.png', 180);
    LatLng latLng = LatLng( newLocalData['lat'], newLocalData['long'] );
      _markers.add( 
           Marker(
              markerId: MarkerId( newLocalData['id'].toString() ),
              position: latLng,
              rotation: newLocalData['heading'].toDouble(),
              draggable: false,
              zIndex: 2,
              flat: true,
              anchor: Offset(0.5, 0.5),
              icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes( markerIcon ))
          );

      _circles.add(
           Circle(
            circleId: CircleId(newLocalData['id'].toString()),
            radius: newLocalData['accuracy'].toDouble(),
            zIndex: 1,
            strokeColor: Colors.blue,
            center: latlng,
            fillColor: Colors.blue.withAlpha(70)
           )
        );
  }
```

Comment: .I am using Geofire for this project but it only sends the drivers latitude and longitude. How have you managed to send drivers heading ?